# Android - Get the current location

Tags: java, android, gps, location

I'm trying to get my current location using this app and displaying them on a Text View with the id of tv_results. Below is my code for getting the location:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView tvResults;
LocationManager locationManager;

//GPS can be from the satellites or from networks (routers or cell networks).
//satellites and networks are Providers
//GPS is always accurate than networks.
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tvResults = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_results);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Service.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    Log.i("HAHA", "GOING!");
    try {
        Log.i("HAHA", "HERE!");
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
        Log.i("HAHA", "IS NOW HERE!");
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        Log.i("PERMISSION_EXCEPTION", "PERMISSION_NOT_GRANTED");
    }

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    try {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1, 1, locationListener);

    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        Log.i("PERMISSION_EXCEPTION", "PERMISSION_NOT_GRANTED");
    }

}

LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        tvResults.setText(location.getLatitude() + ", " + location.getLongitude());
        Log.i("HAHA", String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()) + " " + String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));
        // to get the ways location.getBearing();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        //if naka bukas na siya, tanggalin nyo na yung error message
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }
};

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. ThdroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatemente action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in An
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

And below are my permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

Now you can see that I'm trying to get the location as the user opens the app. However, it doesn't show anything. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: What does your logcat say?

Comment: What you are using to get location - Real device or Emulator?

Comment: This line of code doesn't print anything on the logcat @Buddy: 
           `Log.i("HAHA", String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()) + " " + String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));`

Comment: Do you see any errors/exceptions in your logcat?

Comment: Nope. Don't see any errors @Buddy

Comment: Then you have to wait for some time, till GPS not search for location, as soon as location finds by GPS, it show. For this log the location in logcat in OnLocationChangeListner method

Comment: try getting lastknown location too and also use network provider for getting location too and follow this link to cross check your code
[http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/]